I was trying to use the discord api. But when i enter import discord, it gets several module errors from within the package
enter image description here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\My  PC\OneDrive\Desktop\code\Languages\Python\Docs_disc\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\My  PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import abc, opus, sinks, ui, utils
  File "C:\Users\My  PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .voice_client import VoiceClient, VoiceProtocol
  File "C:\Users\My  PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .player import AudioPlayer, AudioSource
  File "C:\Users\My  PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 29, in <module>
    import audioop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audioop'

im getting these errors when trying to use the Discord.py library.
I already tried uninstalling and installing discord.py and its other alts.
I also updated my python.
Yet, im still getting these errors

It's an issue with discord.py's dependencies, audioop has been deprecated since python 3.11 and removed from stdlib since python 3.13. The simple fix is to install audioop-lts:
pip install audioop-lts


Damn, it's that easy. thank you very much
